# Files preview with spacebar stop to work with some files

Tags: vim, macos-high-sierra

I do a lot of quick preview, selecting the file and hit the spacebar. After a fresh installation of macOS, it doesn't show some of the files (eg. files with not extension created with vim o nano).
Only thing I believe I got different, is that I have not install MacVim.
I got permissions read/writing.
Any idea is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: maybe it's better to ask here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks; I new with Stack Exchange. Still loaning how to post and moving around.